# Unhandled 'error' event happening too often

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I am getting this error on my node server way too often

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (/home/user/nodejs/chat/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/nodejs/chat/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/nodejs/chat/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Connection._handleProtocolError (/home/user/nodejs/chat/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
    at Protocol.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Protocol._delegateError (/home/user/nodejs/chat/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
    at Protocol.end (/home/user/nodejs/chat/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:116:8)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/nodejs/chat/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

Why is that and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you host your database on a free server, the wait timeout is very short.

**wait timeout: the number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it.**

So you can do a query every short period of time to prevent the connection from terminating.

For example

```
SELECT 10;
```

For more detail:-

```
const mysql = require("mysql2");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"URL",
    user:"USER NAME",
    password:"YOUR PASSWORD",
    database:"YOUR DATABASE NAME",
    port:3306,
});


setInterval(()=>{
    connection.query("SELECT 1");
} , 60 * 1000);
```

OR Using Promises

```
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"URL",
    user:"USER NAME",
    password:"YOUR PASSWORD",
    database:"YOUR DATABASE NAME",
    port:3306,
});

setInterval(async()=>{
    (await connection).execute(`SELECT 1`);

} , 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you but where do I do that? Could you please elaborate a little further?

Comment: yes, After establishing the connection. I will rewrite the example

Comment: If there is any problem, try to SELECT from whatever table you have.